# Can not have an ul inside an ol in html

Tags: html, css, list, html-lists

I get the following validation error when I tested my HTML.

Please look at the attached image for the HTML code.
[image]
"Element `ul` not allowed as child of element `ol`in this context."

Comment: Please post code, not images of code.

Answer (score 9):

This is because the content model for `<ol>` (and `<ul>` actually) is [zero or more `li` elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ol-element)

These two tags actually can't contain anything other than `<li>` tags or nothing at all.  If you have `<ol><ul>` browsers will automatically close the `<ol>` tag before beginning the `<ul>` (well, the good ones).

I think your intent is to have:

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <ul>
```

The `<ul>` can be contained inside of an `<li>` that is a child of the `<ol>`.

Answer (score 4):

This is because you should wrap the internal <ul> in a list <li> item:

```
<ul><li>text</li>....</ul>
```

becomes:

```
<li><ul><li>text</li>....</ul></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

**You should do these**

```
<ol>
  ...
  <li>title</li>
  <li><!-- add this -->
    <ul><!-- your ul put here -->
    ...
    </ul>
  </li><!-- add this -->
  ...
</ol>
```

**PS. In some case use original code better than image.**

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap `<ul>` part into a `<li>` tag.

Comment: This could be a much better answer if you put just a little more effort into it. To start, use proper capitalization and punctuation. More importantly, explain *why* wrapping a list in a list item tag would make a difference.