# HTML: Nested <ul> under <ol> validation error

Tags: html, nested, html-lists

i tried to validate a .html file and received this error-
 Error: Element ul not allowed as child of element ol in this context

```
<ol>
   <li><span class="bold">Preheat Oven:</span> Preheat oven </li>
   <li>To Mak</li>
  <ul>
    <li>Whisk together </li>
    <li>Stir in water,.</li>
    <li>Cook over</li>
    <li>Stir in butter.</li>
    <li>Place egg yolks</li>
    <li>Whisk egg yolk . </li>
    <li>Bring to a </li>
    <li>Remove from heat. </li>
    <li>Pour fill.</li>
  </ul>
<li><span class="bold">Make Meringue:</span>  bowl ...</li>
<ul>
<li> woamy.</li>
    <li>Add sugar gradua. </li>
    <li> sealing the edges at the crust.</li>
</ul>
   <li>brown.</li>
</ol>
```

I cannot seems to figure out what I did wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just wrap the <ul> in a <li>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the unordered list in list item tags, otherwise they are just floating around in the middle of no where:

```
<ol>
    <li><span class="bold">Preheat Oven:</span> Preheat oven </li>
    <li>To Mak</li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>Whisk together </li>
            <li>Stir in water,.</li>
            <li>Cook over</li>
            <li>Stir in butter.</li>
            <li>Place egg yolks</li>
            <li>Whisk egg yolk . </li>
            <li>Bring to a </li>
            <li>Remove from heat. </li>
            <li>Pour fill.</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><span class="bold">Make Meringue:</span>  bowl ...</li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li> woamy.</li>
            <li>Add sugar gradua. </li>
            <li> sealing the edges at the crust.</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>brown.</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score -1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15870503/8179067 i think the answer can be founded in this topic :)
"

> This is because the content model for  (and  actually) is zero or more li elements
>
> These two tags actually can't contain anything other than
>
> tags or nothing at all. If you have  browsers will automatically close the  tag before beginning the  (well, the good ones).

try with this one :)